# Logging done right

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, c#-2.0

So my problem is about logging, and how to handle the log statements which can have influence on your code and your runtime behavior.

Log files... every program should write those for propper problem solving but how to do it right?

The most log-statements are verry expensive to get because they should provide usefull information and they are always built even the logging is disabled totaly.

The logging can be configured by xmls, inCode or in some settings etc. but this doesn't solve the string building problem.

For example the following code is always loading a huge lazy loaded tree which would never be loaded totaly during normal execution.

The whole tree is only created for this logging statement to be displayed in the log file

(*Ok, I know..., but this is just a replacement for all the complex logging methods that exists in the most programs which should never be executed during normal release execution*)

```
public void SomeMethod(){
    logger.Debug(someObject.GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree());
}
```

The Method `someObject.GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree()` is always invoked even if logging is turned off, so there are some common solutions for this problem like:

```
public void SomeMethod(){
#if DEBUG
    logger.Debug(someObject.GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree());
#endif       
}

public void SomeMethod(){
    if(logger.DoLogDebug())
        logger.Debug(someObject.GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree());
}
```

I think it's clear that the `#if DEBUG` compiler flag is no solution for productive code.
If I use the `logger.DoLogDebug()` there would be excessive code for checking if the logging is enabled... so this can't be the solution either.

I thought the `ConditionalAttribute` could help but it's also bound to the compiler flags and it doesn't deactivate the call to `GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree`

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]  
public void Debug(string debugMessage) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(debugMessage); 
}
```

So I'm looking for a logging solution which

- is not excessive currupting my source code with debug statements
- where the logging level is decided during runtime not at compiletime
- where the statements are only resolved if neccessary (logLevel > definedLogLevel)

Extra loglines for the best answer ;-)

Edited: I'm looking for a solution in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to 'lazy logging' is to use an expression (to create a function delegate that returns the message) rather than using direct evaluation:

```
logger.Debug(() => someObject.GetHeavyDescriptionFromLazyTree());
```

This has its own downsides (construction of the delegate), but it can be cheaper than the expensive method.  Typically you would provide this as an overload and only use it in the case where you know evaluating the expression is expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this sounds great but I forgott, it has to be solved with .NET 2.0 :-(

Comment: @oberfreak, in that case, I think the standard 'if' check is your best bet; hopefully you don't have very many places where the logging is so expensive.

Comment: Why should the aproach do _not_ work with .NET 2.0? I do this all the time with VS.NET 2010 and .NET 2.0 as a the target platform.

Comment: @oberfreak: if you want .NET 2.0 only as target environment, but have the .NET 3.5 compiler (VS 2008 or 2010) for your development, then this will work either. With VS 2003, of course, this won't work.

Comment: Didn't even thought about it... nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> The most log-statements are verry expensive to get because they should provide usefull information and they are always built even the logging is disabled totaly.

Not precisely true.  See here:

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    StackFrame f = new StackFrame(2);
    Log.Debug("Very expensive message to put together and stuff." + f.GetMethod().Name);
}
```

Your message won't be built if debug logging isn't enabled at all.  This satisfies all three of your conditions and is fairly standard practice.

Edit:  I should add that `IsDebugEnabled` takes into account whether debug logging is enabled globally *and* any override configuration *for this particular logger*.  It's very specific, and is determined at runtime, but is also cached until the configuration changes.

Edit2:

> If I use the logger.DoLogDebug() there would be excessive code for checking if the logging is enabled... so this can't be the solution either.

The if statement I outlined above isn't excessive and is evaluated very quickly.  I suggest you experiment with it and evaluate for yourself if it is performant enough.  If you are finding that you have these `if` blocks *all over the place*, the standard suggestion is to consolidate them when possible.

A key idea here is log4net has *five* logging levels, each of which can be considered completely independently of the others.  So you might have `IsDebugEnabled` in one place, and `IsInfoEnabled` in another place.  You won't get this with conditional compilation very easily, and that would prove even *more* cumbersome.  This scenario is actually quite common in code I've worked on:

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    StackFrame f = new StackFrame(2);
    Log.Debug("Very expensive message to put together and stuff." + f.GetMethod().Name);
}
if (Log.IsInfoEnabled)
{
    StackFrame f = new StackFrame(2);
    Log.Debug("Very expensive message to put together and stuff." + f.GetMethod().Name);
}
if (Log.IsErrorEnabled)
{
    StackFrame f = new StackFrame(2);
    Log.Debug("Very expensive message to put together and stuff." + f.GetMethod().Name);
}
```

If you want to be able to tailor your log outputs by logging level and by class, or even by entire namespaces, this is the way to go.

Comment: This is indeed the recommended "fastest" way, according to Log4Net's FAQ: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#perf-not-logging

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm sorry.I don't want the logging decision code in my businesslogic so it can be extended/exchanged easily. If the decision would take place in the BL it would be more than a thousand lines to check each time you (for example) want to introduce a new logging level. So I think i wouldn't be flexible enough in the future. (The Software is going to have a aprx. ALS of 10-15 Years, so it should be extendable and maintainable)

Comment: @oberfreak, the decision would come strictly from the log4net configuration, nowhere in your code.  Libraries being used from another program would use that programs configuration, not their own.

Comment: @Inuyasha yes, that is my next problem :-) so i think im going with the delegate and the lamda expression to also solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can make it configurable by the web.config or app.config. Add a item called EnableLogging `(<add key="EnableLogging" value="false"/>)`. Then create a static method that gets the value from the .config and used that to check.

Comment: I think you almost completely missed the point of the question.

Comment: I think this would go along with his option two DoLogDebug() check except the method would not need much logic in it. After all what is simpler than getting a appsettings value from the web.config or app.config.

Comment: "EnableLogging" isn't even a log4net configuration key.  Why would you do this when log4net already has its own enabling configuration functionality?

Comment: You are right Inuyasha, i missed the fact that he tagged this question with log4net. You are absolute correct. Log4net provides its own option.